# Range of Input Loop in C

Tags: c

I've been trying to find out how to make a program that loops while the input is out of range and which rejects invalid input like alphabets or nothing input into the program.  I found one solution, but it uses a range of numbers  1-99 as accepted values. I want to be able make the range 1-20 or then 1-any specified range, but when I tried to modify the program, it stops working properly. Does anyone know how to change this program so that the range is different (ex 1-20 or 1-30), but the program still works as it should, meaning it tells the user if the number out of range, if nothing is input, or if incorrect symbols are input. Also, if someone manages to do this, could you please explain to me what the logic behind it is?

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

int main() {

    printf("\nProgram Start.....\n\n");

    char userInput[64];
    int num = 0;
    char temp;
    size_t length = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    while( num == 0 ) {

        length = 0;
        flag = 0;
        num = 0;

        printf("Please enter a number 1 to 99:");
        fgets(userInput, 63, stdin);
        length = strlen(userInput);

        if( length < 2 || length > 3) {
            printf("Invalid strlen()\n");
            continue;
        }

        length--;

        for(index = 0; index < length; ++index) {
            if(userInput[index] < '0' || userInput[index] > '9') {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if( flag) {
            printf("Invalid character\n");
            continue;
        }

        if( sscanf(userInput, "%d", &num) != 1) {
            printf("Invalid sscanf()\n");
            continue;
        }

        if( num < 1 || num > 99) {
            printf("Invalid range\n");
            continue;
        }

        printf("Number OK:%d\n",num);
    }

    printf("\nProgram Quit.....\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use variables as the range. You can scan in some numbers by using scanf().

Comment: How did you try to modify the program to meet your 1-20 requirement?

Comment: @Degustaf, I tried to modify the last if statement:                                                     if( num < 1 || num > 99) {
            printf("Invalid range\n");
            continue;
        }                                                                                                                   by changing the range to num < 1 || num >20. After doing this, the program just prints "Program Quit"  and exits, if I input a value that is not between 1-20. I want the program to scan the user's input again after this. That's the problem.

Comment: @grammer I'm surprised that didn't work.  How does it not work properly?  What did you change that line to?

Comment: changed it to this: if( num < 1 || num > 20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start by seeing what goes wrong if we just change `if( num < 1 || num > 99)` to `if( num < 1 || num > 20)` where the input is 25.  If we reach that test, we have already assigned 25 to `num` with `sscanf`, so the conditional passes, we print out the error message, and `continue` moves us back to the `while` statement:

```
while( num == 0 )
```

Since we've already assigned a non-zero value to `num`, we fail this test, and exit the loop.  to fix this, we can adjust the `if` block to

```
if( num < 1 || num > 99) {
    printf("Invalid range\n");
    num = 0;
    continue;
}
```

---

**Why wasn't this an issue in the original program?**

In the original program, you have already verified that the input is a 2 digit number before you get to that check.  So, the only way that it can fail is if `num` is 0, so when continue throws us back to the `while` statement, we reenter the loop.

Comment: I tried the following solution and it worked. Many thanks for you help.                       if( num < 1 || num > 99) {
    printf("Invalid range\n");
    num = 0;
    continue;
}

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the original program works, it seems that you could just replace

`if( num < 1 || num > 99)` with `if( num < LOW || num > HIGH)`, where `LOW` and `HIGH` represent the range you're looking to include. For the case of 1-30, you'd use:

```
int LOW=1, HIGH=30;
```

You might also want to update the instructions, eg:

```
printf("Please enter a number %d to %d:", LOW, HIGH);
```

If you want the user to be queried again for an invalid range, you just need to make sure your while loop will not terminate when the user enters an invalid range. Since the control statement is `while ( num == 0 )`, you just need to set `num = 0` if the user enters a number in an invalid range. Eg:

```
    if( num < LOW || num > HIGH) {
        printf("Invalid range\n");
        num = 0;
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: Hi. I tried that. It causes the problem. When I input a number out of the range of 1-20 or 1-20, the program prints "Invalid range" which is correct, but then it quits, instead of scanning for more input. That's the problem. I need ti scan for input again.